# AJAX website doesn't get indexed properly

Tags: google, google-search, ajax

Why http://anuary.com doesn't get indexed properly?

I've submitted the sitemap ( http://anuary.com/?sitemap=true ) almost a month ago. However, 0 pages appear in Google index.

I've also prepared the webpage infrastructure following Google AJAX-friendly pages guide ( http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html ), therefore

```
http://anuary.com/#!/portfolio/28
```

becomes

```
http://anuary.com/?_escaped_fragment_=!/portfolio/28
```

However, I am not sure what to do with the landing page, http://anuary.com/ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't mapping your hasbangs correctly.

`http://anuary.com/#!/portfolio/28` should become:

`http://anuary.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/portfolio/28`

Also, the Google guidelines tells you that pages without hash fragments you simply include:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Having some internal link structure and getting rid of duplicate URLs also can't hurt. Even if Google can access URLs listed in your sitemap, they may choose not to index them or to relegate them to the supplementary index if they're perceived to be low quality/value. If no one links to them, not even your own pages, then Google might choose to skip over them as well.

Answer (score 2):

This query seems to return all the pages visible to google http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site:anuary.com&hl=en&noj=1&site=webhp&prmd=imvns&filter=0&biw=1920&bih=936

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, though – why the other pages are not indexed? Furthermore, why `dev.anuary.com` is indexed if `http://dev.anuary.com/robots.txt` clearly says not to.

Comment: In essence there is nothing but the pages shown in the query to index - crawling your site with xenu produces the homepage only. Have you signed up for webmaster tools and submitted the sitemap that way. Why take this approach for such a simple site?

Comment: I've only built the base so far, on top of which I want to add new features. Though, clearly I want to sort out Google index issue first. As per the information provided in the question body, I did already submit sitemap to Google.

Comment: @Guy: It does sorta answer your question. You said it's been almost a month and 0 pages have been indexed. That search link clearly proves otherwise. Google doesn't always add all pages of a site immediately (or ever). They've index 2 of the 4 pages on your site. That's already 50% of your site in less than a month, which is not bad for a site with almost no content, bad markup, poor accessibility design, and almost no internal link structure, and probably few external backlinks.

Comment: @Guy apologies for the very short answer I was in a big hurry and really should have left a comment not an answer. Lese Majeste did expand correctly on my somewhat hidden point.